# How can I add condition in rules laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request, laravel-5.3, rules

My controller like this :

```
<?php
use App\Http\Requests\StoreReceiveOrderRequest;
class SellController extends Controller
{
    public function receiveOrder(StoreReceiveOrderRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        ...
    }
}
```

Before executed statement in the receiveOrder method, it will check rules on the StoreReceiveOrderRequest

The StoreReceiveOrderRequest like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class StoreReceiveOrderRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'is_follow_up'=>'required',
            'note'=>'max:300' // I want to make this to be required if is_follow_up = n
        ];
    }
}
```

the result of `dd($request->all());`, there are 2 results, depending user input

If the is_follow_up = y, the result like this :

```
Array
(
    [is_follow_up] => y
)
```

If the is_follow_up = n, the result like this :

```
Array
(
    [is_follow_up] => n
    [note] => test
)
```

If is_follow_up = n, I want to make the note is required

If is_follow_up = y, the note is not required

Seems it must to add condition on the rules

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a validation rule that does exactly this already. The Laravel docs for validation list all the available rules.

```
'note' => 'required_if:is_follow_up,n|...'
```

[Laravel 5.3 - Docs - Validation - Rule - required if](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726407/how-can-i-add-condition-based-on-the-parameters-of-the-array-data-on-the-rules-l. This is a bit different

Answer (score 2):

Just change your validation to the following-

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    class StoreReceiveOrderRequest extends FormRequest
    {
       public function rules()
       {
         $rules = ['is_follow_up'=>'required',
           ];

         if (Input::get('is_follow_up')=='n') {
          $rules += [
             'note'=>'max:300'
          ];
         }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your conditions in Laravel Request File

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'order' => ['nullable', 'integer'],
            'type' => ['required', 'in:category,brand,vendor,image'],
            'category_id' => ['required_if:type,category'],
            'brand_id' => ['required_if:type,brand'],
            'vendor_id' => ['required_if:type,vendor'],
            'image_size' => ['required_if:type,image','in:small,medium,large'],
            'images.*' => ['required_if:type,image'],
            
            'image_links' => ['required_if:type,image,url'],
        ];

        if (request()->get('image_size') == 'large') {
            $rules += [
                'images' => 'max:1',
            ];
        } elseif (request()->get('image_size') == 'medium') {
            $rules += [
                'images' => 'min:2|max:2',
            ];
        } elseif (request()->get('image_size') == 'small') {
            $rules += [
                'images' => 'min:3|max:3',
            ];
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Read The Laravel docs for list of all the available validation rules.

```
'note' => 'required_if:is_follow_up,n|...'
```

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726407/how-can-i-add-condition-based-on-the-parameters-of-the-array-data-on-the-rules-l. This is a bit different

Comment: @akramwahld i really dont understand what is the point of posting the same answer that is already here ... 2 days later

Comment: @lagbox ,its none of your business, i can answer any question at anytime I can, and its very apparent am not violating SO rules,

Comment: i wasn't implying there was a violation of rules, it is none of my business, sorry for the confusion